# Upload file to SharePoint private group via REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, java

I want to know how to upload files to SharePoint private Group via REST API.

1. How to get SharePoint private Group folder?
2. How to upload file to this private Group folder?

Here is link of my private group.
https://my_site.sharepoint.com/sites/private_group/Shared%20Documents/Forms

The uploading file is needed in Android Application(Written in Java) and I am new in SharePoint.
So I hear your experiences and helpful advice. Thanks.
Hope to hear from you soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant private group as SharePoint team site with private office 365 group connected.

**How to upload files in sharepoint online document library using the REST API?**

- **Client Id** – will get it from the SharePoint online page.
- **Client Secret** – will get it from the SharePoint online page.
- **Realm (Tenant Id)** – will get it from the postman tool.
- **Access Token** – will get from postman tool.
- Do a sample upload POST operation using the postman tool, once successful upload, get the REST API code and use in your actual project code.

Here is a details step by tutorial how to upload files in SharePoint online using the REST API and postman tool :

[In 4 steps access SharePoint online data using postman tool](https://www.google.com/amp/s/global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/in-4-steps-access-sharepoint-online-data-using-postman-tool/amp/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I decided to upload files to Shared Document folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Java lib that both support Android and PC and it could help to upload file to SharePoint , you may take a reference:

- [(Java) SharePoint -- Upload File](https://www.example-code.com/java/sharepoint_upload_file.asp)

And you could also have a look the behind rest API:

- [create a file and add it to a folder.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest#working-with-files-by-using-rest)

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I decided to upload files to Shared Document folder.